# How add empty_value for multiple choice

Tags: php

I have two fields: Choices for year and input field for Articles. When The user do not write any choice for articles in the input field, that mean it should display all the articles in one year. I changed this input field by a choice for multiple choices, I just added the name of my articles. After this modification I don't add the option ALL. This following the small code from my routes:

Old code:

```
->add('lru', 'text', array(
   'data' => '',
   'required' => FALSE))
```

New code:

```
 ->add('lru', 'choice', array(
 'choices' => array(
'\'ATSU\'' => 'ATSU',
 .
 .
 .
 ),
'required' => FALSE,
'empty_value' => 'ALL',
'empty_data' => NULL,
'multiple' => TRUE
```

I did a research of 'empty_value' I found that This option only applies if both the expanded and multiple options are set to false. I changed

```
'multiple' => FALSE
```

It became works well.
My library are:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

this following my small code of the `form`:

```
$user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();
        $default = 'ALL';
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')->setMethod('GET')
                ->add('currency', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'USD' => 'Dollar',
                        'EUR' => 'Euro'),
                ))
                ->add('nature', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array( .....),

                ->add('year', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(date('Y') => date('Y'),
                        date('Y') - 1 => date('Y') - 1,
                        date('Y') - 2 => date('Y') - 2,
                        date('Y') - 3 => date('Y') - 3,
                        date('Y') - 4 => date('Y') - 4,
                        'Yearly' => 'Yearly'),
                    'required' => TRUE,
                ))
                  ->add('lru', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(

                      // I want add the default value ALL here but I don't understand how


                    '\'ATSU\'' => 'ATSU', .... )


                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'ALL',
                    'empty_data' => NULL,
                    'multiple' => TRUE
                      ))
```

tell me please how can I change my code, and I keep my choice for `multiple choice`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a default object or array to form builder.

Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#setting-default-values.

In your case it can be something like this:

```
<?php

$user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();
        $default = 'ALL';
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form',['lru' => [$default]])->setMethod('GET')
                ->add('currency', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'USD' => 'Dollar',
                        'EUR' => 'Euro'),
                ))
                ->add('nature', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array( .....),

                ->add('year', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(date('Y') => date('Y'),
                        date('Y') - 1 => date('Y') - 1,
                        date('Y') - 2 => date('Y') - 2,
                        date('Y') - 3 => date('Y') - 3,
                        date('Y') - 4 => date('Y') - 4,
                        'Yearly' => 'Yearly'),
                    'required' => TRUE,
                ))
                  ->add('lru', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(

                      // I want add the default value ALL here but I don't understand how

                    $default => $default,

                    '\'ATSU\'' => 'ATSU', .... )


                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'ALL',
                    'empty_data' => NULL,
                    'multiple' => TRUE
                      ))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems a good solution but I'm sorry I can't understand how I should add it. because I want add just a default value "ALL". I changed my question above you can see my form please can suggest me how can I do it.

Comment: please some suggestion from you.

Comment: it return this error: Unable to transform value for property path "[lru]": Expected an array.

Comment: answer updated. wrap $defaults into array :: [$defaults]